# Need help appending info to an empty list

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, data-analysis

I am new to coding. I was trying to scrape the Indeed website for jobs. I was able to scrape job titles, company name, and location using selenium find_element. I want to know how I can now append these titles in an empty list, the same for company names and location. And then put all that information together in a DataFrame.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import datetime
import selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdrivermanager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from lxml import etree as et
from csv import writer
import time
from time import sleep
import threading
import random
from random import randint

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--incognito")

options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)

#define jobs
job_keywords = ['data+analyst', 'ux+designer', 'marketing+coordinator',
                       'business+analyst', 'marketing+assistant']

#define location
loc_keywords = ['Ontario', 'Kitchener-Waterloo%2C+ON', 'London%2C+ON']

#url
url = "https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=Kitchener-Waterloo%2C+ON&vjk=8513d6c9ab34a216"
url


#create driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

for i in range(0, 200, 10):
    driver.get(url = 'https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q=data+analyst&l=Kitchener-Waterloo%2C+ON&vjk=8513d6c9ab34a216' + str())
    
    html_page = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page, 'lxml')
    
    time.sleep(3)

    #getting job titles
    job_title = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"jobTitle")

       
    #getting company names
    company_name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"companyName")
    
    #location
    location = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"companyLocation")
    
    #joblink
    link = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a").get_attribute("href")
    link
    
    #creating lists
    
    job_titles_list = []
    company_names_list = []
    job_locations = []
    job_link = []
    
    job_page = driver.find_element(By.ID,"mosaic-jobResults")
    jobs = job_page.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"job_seen_beacon") 

    for ii in jobs: 
        # Finding the job title and its related elements
        job_title = ii.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"jobTitle")
        job_titles_list.append(job_title.text)
        job_link.append(job_title.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a").get_attribute("href"))
```

This is what my code looks like.
I basically wanna learn how I can get the job titles I fetched to add to an empty list. And then be able to loop the process so the code runs on multiple pages on Indeed. And then I can have a data set that contains all the jobs, locations, and company names and links`your text` to jobs.

I figured out the part on how to get one element but I'm confused with the loops and appending.
I tried different solutions and it gave me an empty list.

output :

```
>>> Jobs
[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
>>> job_title[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way to get all the jobs from all the available pages and put all of them into a Python `List` of Dictionary where each dictionary holds the details of an individual job post in a key-value pair.

```py
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def all_page_job_search(query, location):
    # Configure ChromeOptions to run the Chrome browser in incognito mode
    options = ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--incognito")

    # Initialize the Chrome driver and WebDriverWait
    driver = Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # Open the Indeed job search page with the provided query and location
    driver.get(f"https://ca.indeed.com/jobs?q={query}&l={location}")

    total_job_list = []  # List to store all job details

    while True:
        # Wait until all job elements are present on the page
        jobs = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.job_seen_beacon')))

        # Loop through each job element and extract job details
        for job in jobs:
            job_title = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.jobTitle").text
            company_name = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.companyName").text
            location = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.companyLocation").text
            job_link = job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2.jobTitle>a").get_attribute("href")

            # Append the job details to the total_job_list
            total_job_list.append({
                "job_title": job_title,
                "company_name": company_name,
                "location": location,
                "job_link": job_link
            })

        try:
            # Look for the "Next" button to navigate to the next page of job listings
            next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[data-testid="pagination-page-next"]')))
            next_button.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            # If the "Next" button is not found, it means there are no more pages, so break the loop
            break

        try:
            # Check if a popup appears and close it (if present)
            popup_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div#mosaic-desktopserpjapopup>div>button[aria-label="close"]')))
            popup_button.click()
        except TimeoutException:
            # If no popup is found, continue without any action
            pass

    # Print the total number of jobs found and return the list of job details
    print(f"Total Jobs for {query} in {location}: {len(total_job_list)}")
    return total_job_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Call the function with the desired query and location
    print(all_page_job_search(query='data analyst', location='Kitchener-Waterloo, ON'))
```

output:

```
Total Jobs for data analyst in Waterloo, ON: 46
[{'job_title': 'Data Analyst', 'company_name': 'University of Waterloo', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=fcf1281ca2ad0bae&fccid=5bcffa6277080afe&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Analyst (Data Analytics and Reporting Team)', 'company_name': 'University of Waterloo', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=6a54004a21e70c6e&fccid=5bcffa6277080afe&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Data Analyst', 'company_name': 'MAXON Computer', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=9db552e2dbdb7caa&fccid=b6a6198234d75b79&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Bank Digital Insights Analyst', 'company_name': 'Manulife', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=395618acf63c34d1&fccid=1747adf6142beb48&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'analyst, database', 'company_name': 'Aarorn Technologies Inc.', 'location': 'Guelph, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=44488c921c711c73&fccid=928eebc726e33a2e&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Health Promotion & Research Analyst (Public Health)', 'company_name': 'Region of Waterloo', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=8513d6c9ab34a216&fccid=cb43ce2ddf90903e&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Enterprise Data Governance Analyst', 'company_name': 'D2L', 'location': 'Kitchener, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=887668286c9e6133&fccid=7c3a25cdc8e47610&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Business Intelligence Analyst', 'company_name': 'Manulife', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=be0a827fd84b0835&fccid=1747adf6142beb48&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Business Systems Analyst', 'company_name': 'University of Waterloo', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=17cd3cdcfc2a2dff&fccid=5bcffa6277080afe&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'HR Workday Business Analyst', 'company_name': 'University of Waterloo', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=0ea862aed09333e0&fccid=5bcffa6277080afe&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Cloud Infrastructure Analyst', 'company_name': 'Sun Life', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=3205ecb5680b2d91&fccid=618943d89d0005a6&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Programmer/Analyst, Data Services', 'company_name': 'Sleeman Breweries', 'location': 'Guelph, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=99d84bb40952b79b&fccid=2fef090306160696&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Junior Analyst, Sustainable Investing', 'company_name': 'Addenda Capital', 'location': 'Guelph, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=47058318a0ce8f09&fccid=e0bbddd21984445e&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Manager, Data Analytics and Business Intelligence', 'company_name': 'University of Waterloo', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=cfcbcb0bf5d97c24&fccid=5bcffa6277080afe&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Business Analyst, Health Information System', 'company_name': 'Grand River Hospital', 'location': 'Kitchener, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=22eb1849f9bd95ea&fccid=a463ca7249c5270f&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Program Analyst (Client Services & Waterloo Region Housing)', 'company_name': 'Region of Waterloo', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=2af8de2ad6c17e29&fccid=cb43ce2ddf90903e&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Corporate Energy Analyst', 'company_name': 'Region of Waterloo', 'location': 'Kitchener, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=04027a65abd77755&fccid=cb43ce2ddf90903e&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Sr. Investigation Analyst - Drug', 'company_name': 'Manulife', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=631779f713e6fcb5&fccid=1747adf6142beb48&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Sr. Business Systems Analyst', 'company_name': 'Open Text Corporation', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=01e7f04fe1610b1a&fccid=c908408e676247d6&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'SCADA & Information System Analyst (Water)', 'company_name': 'Region of Waterloo', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=bcd6c3ed5096d263&fccid=cb43ce2ddf90903e&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Operations, Risk and Controls, Senior Analyst', 'company_name': 'Manulife', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=fff23605a7bdffd2&fccid=1747adf6142beb48&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Lead Service Management Analyst(Problem\\Change Management)', 'company_name': 'Open Text Corporation', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=256031aef7db1c82&fccid=c908408e676247d6&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Lead Service Management Analyst(Major Incident Management)', 'company_name': 'Open Text Corporation', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=8563d5fde3de9edb&fccid=c908408e676247d6&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Sr. Business Systems Analyst', 'company_name': 'opentext', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=356ff992ffedbde5&fccid=c908408e676247d6&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Lead Service Management Analyst(Problem\\Change Management)', 'company_name': 'opentext', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=289172ee3cfc0e79&fccid=c908408e676247d6&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Senior Actuarial Analyst (Pricing), Personal Insurance', 'company_name': 'Definity Financial Corporation', 'location': 'Hybrid remote in Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=15fe3dcfd34367a0&fccid=236ef8b5fc73dcdc&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Lead Service Management Analyst(Major Incident Management)', 'company_name': 'opentext', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=a2818036ce7c7628&fccid=c908408e676247d6&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Business Data Analyst', 'company_name': 'RideCo', 'location': 'Hybrid remote in Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=5d822d7df36dd954&fccid=e04c335ad3aed20a&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Business Analyst', 'company_name': 'Reliance Home Comfort', 'location': 'Cambridge, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=6b69a47a70672a97&fccid=9aa40cd2accb7367&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Senior Actuarial Analyst - Commercial Pricing', 'company_name': 'Definity Financial Corporation', 'location': 'Hybrid remote in Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=bdfb27d7adfac60d&fccid=236ef8b5fc73dcdc&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Business System Analyst', 'company_name': 'Heartland Farm Mutual Inc.', 'location': 'Remote in Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=0a21fd408319d7a1&fccid=a45ec34697774b3f&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Reports Analyst- Chengyeng', 'company_name': 'Majorel', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=5e169c6cb94d1183&fccid=afe85deef9b97f13&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Operations Business Analyst', 'company_name': 'AirBoss of America Corp.', 'location': 'Kitchener, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=af1c878d42141f98&fccid=293718897fd9eee7&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Data and BI Analyst', 'company_name': 'Challenger Motor Freight Inc.', 'location': 'Cambridge, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=1403a87b1f8d8fb8&fccid=ba5d3347df98493d&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Senior Business Intelligence Analyst', 'company_name': 'System1', 'location': 'Hybrid remote in Guelph, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=83f15fc1e72f8aa4&fccid=0471f3a5f9f7f44f&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Reports Analyst - Chengyeng - Onsite', 'company_name': 'Majorel', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=790c92cdf4c076f7&fccid=afe85deef9b97f13&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Senior Technical Data Analyst', 'company_name': 'System1', 'location': 'Hybrid remote in Guelph, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=59a4342a8bc1dfe9&fccid=0471f3a5f9f7f44f&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Lead Technical Data Analyst', 'company_name': 'System1', 'location': 'Hybrid remote in Guelph, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=47e8e0ff0457c3f7&fccid=0471f3a5f9f7f44f&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Logistics Analyst', 'company_name': 'Glen Dimplex Americas', 'location': 'Cambridge, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=197ca8ea5cebc71a&fccid=45d24101b4e14332&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Business Systems Analyst, Senior - Corporate', 'company_name': 'Equitable Life of Canada', 'location': 'Hybrid remote in Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=edbca5b2d89a299e&fccid=ac28bc2d58529cfc&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Actuarial Analyst', 'company_name': 'Heartland Farm Mutual Inc.', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=4b5f46f0b27a4587&fccid=a45ec34697774b3f&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'IT Governance, Risk and Compliance Analyst', 'company_name': 'Equitable Life of Canada', 'location': 'Hybrid remote in Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=31cb7ea4604202d4&fccid=ac28bc2d58529cfc&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Board Certified Behaviour Analyst (BCBA)', 'company_name': 'Barrantes & Associates Inc.', 'location': 'Guelph, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/company/Barrantes-&-Associates-Inc./jobs/Board-Certified-Behavior-Analyst-ff8add7ef1724226?fccid=1daa18b4ed89f871&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Senior Compliance Analyst - Market Conduct Audit', 'company_name': 'Equitable Life of Canada', 'location': 'Hybrid remote in Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=b3d6d719b9778538&fccid=ac28bc2d58529cfc&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Technical Support Analyst, Supply Chain', 'company_name': 'Restaurant Brands International', 'location': 'Guelph, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=7c1ca9747c183fdb&fccid=1bf77f1dd2c2631f&vjs=3'}, {'job_title': 'Business Analyst, Enterprise Project Mgmt Office (Contract)', 'company_name': 'Gowling WLG', 'location': 'Waterloo, ON', 'job_link': 'https://ca.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=8df7b7ed8ef56ef2&fccid=efc2213aea431503&vjs=3'}]
```

reference: https://github.com/ajeet214/Web_Scraping_with_Selenium/blob/main/indeed_com.py